# scroll bar for t:datatable

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I am using a  How do I add a vertical scroll bar?

I tried following but that did not work

```
    <t:dataTable  style="scroll:auto"  class="display dataTable"  id="abc" border="1"   value="#{ManageBean.selectItems}" var="feed"     > 
     <h:column >
          <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Name" />
          </f:facet>
  </h:column>
  </t:dataTable>
```

And the jquery code is as follows

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ManageOutboundIdentitiesForm\\:abc').dataTable( {
    "sScrollY": "20px"
} );

   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to wrap the `dataTable` into a div and add some CSS. Example

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 30%; height: 20%;">
     <t:dataTable..../>
     </t:dataTable>
</div>
```

I'm just guessing the sizes for `width` and `height` here so change them as needed.